# reading files in order of a number in file name

Tags: regex, string, matlab, text-processing

I have some images which I want to load and process. The images are named as follows: `image1.jpg`, `image2.jpg`, `image3.jpg`, etc. When I process each image, I want to store the output in an array. It is important that the index in this array corresponds to the image name. For example, the value in array element `5` should correspond to `image5.jpg`.

The problem is that when I search for these files and load them, they are loaded strictly alphabetically, rather than numerically. So, because I have over a hunder images, the first few to be loaded are: `image1.jpg`, `image10.jpg`, `image100.jpg`, `image101.jpg`, `image102.jpg`, and so on. Therefore, array element `5` will correspond to `image102.jpg`.

My question is: how can I load the files in order of the number in the filename, rather than the default ordering?

Here is my code to get the filenames:

```
my_dir = dir('C:/MyDir');
image_files = {my_dir(~[my_dir.isdir]).name};
disp(image_files);
```

Which gives the output:

```
'image1.jpg'    'image10.jpg'    'image100.jpg'    'image101.jpg'    'image102.jpg'   .....
```

Answer (score 3):

`regexp` gets the job done too:

```
C = regexp(image_files,'image(\d*).jpg','tokens','once');
[~,inds] = sort(str2double([C{:}]))
image_files_sorted = image_files(inds)
```

Comment: +1 I like this better than my answer, because it avoids `cellfun`. Also, `regexp` allows more flexibility if the filename pattern changes

Answer (score 2):

To sort the cell array `image_files`:

1. Keep just the part of each string that is known to contain only numbers
2. Convert that to a number
3. Sort all those numbers and get the sorting index
4. Use that index to sort the original cell array.

Code:

```
image_files =  {'image1.jpg' 'image10.jpg' 'image100.jpg' 'image2.jpg' 'image20.jpg'};
[~, ind] = sort(cellfun(@(c) str2num(c(6:end-4)), image_files))
image_files_sorted = image_files(ind);
```

Result:

```
image_files_sorted = 
    'image1.jpg'    'image2.jpg'    'image10.jpg'    'image20.jpg'    'image100.jpg'
```

Comment: Slick use of `cellfun`, no doubt. +1 But I like `regexp` for pattern matching.